RabbitMq low CPU usage
I have a somewhat peculiar problem with RabbitMq - it uses too little CPU.
I am running a single RabbitMq node v3.11.13 on a Debian server with 64 CPUs and 200GB RAM.
The usual usage looks like this: 350 connections / 380 channels / 121 queues / 300 consumers.
I am getting very poor performance out of the system (1-3k messages/s publish, 500-1k messages/s delivery) and overall the rabbitmq server is very unresponsive, although it uses very little CPU.
Looking at htop I get this picture:

I use confirm channels and the publish confirm ack arrives very late after each message is published (5-30 seconds delay).
Also the management interface is very slow to respond to any clicks.
The amount of messages in the queues varies from 5k to 50k, but this is due mainly to the high latency, my consumers have greater processing capacity but they simply don't get messages fast enough from the server, so they idle around.
I am suspecting there is some configuration issue here that is limiting the amount of CPU cores that Rabbit can use. There seems to be no other reason, since no system resources are the limiting factor (plenty of free RAM and CPU, disk activity very low, no waiting times, network traffic low).
Is there a way to configure how many CPU cores get allocated to the RabbitMq server? If no, what could be causing this low throughput, low responsiveness, low system load problem?

how does iostat -x 10 look? Have you looked at https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/runtime? Each core runs single threaded IIRC. Durable queues with persistent messages are a lot slower than non-durable queues. You also want to look at rabbitmq-diagnostics observer...

Turns out the reason was that too many processes were competing for the CPUs; the server tried to do too many things at once and in the end it did none of them well.
The server was constantly switching between tasks and none of them could make use of the CPUs fully.
I moved RabbitMq out, onto a separate machine and both the Rabbit and other services that remained on the original machine now perform as expected, CPU usage went up on both machines and the responsiveness just as well.
